# Base64 Image lost in Android WebView after returning to Activity

Tags: android, image, webview, base64

We have a Base64 encoded Image Resource in our WebView like
 `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>`. 
It seems that its working when the  WebView is first display but it is lost after the Activity is resumed. Has anybody similar problems? Is this a know error? Is there a know workaround besides not using Base64 images.

Comment: could you please paste the relevant code.

Comment: plz check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5335274/1554935)