# im html only shows text but no images.

Tags: android

I am getting HTML tag in JSON which contains images. When I load in WebView does not show any image, why?

I want to show HTML in WebView which displays an image and TextView both but my code only shows text but no images.

Any idea why?

```
WebView      wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);


   String   htmldescription = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");

wv.loadData(htmldescription, "text/html", "utf8");

              {"Status":1,
          "data":
 [
  {"product_id":"8569",


 "image":"data\/osc\/0\/10011-Scalp-Med-Hsdf.jpg",
  "manufacturer_id":"0",

 "name":"Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004..",

  "description":"<p><b><font face="Arial">Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004.. <\/font><\/b><\/p>    
  \r\n\r  
 \n<p><img border="0" height="257"
  src="http:\/\/www.megamall.com.pk\/image\/cache\/data\/10011-Scalp-Med-Hairfall-Solution- 
 800x800.jpg" width="261" \/><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p><b><font face="Arial" size="2">
 Features: <\/font><\/b><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p><font face="Arial" size="2"><b>Scalp Med Hair 
  Grow<\/b>    is an all natural formulation which includes the pure extracts of plants from 
 3 different continents.<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nIs your Bald Spot getting bigger and bigger 
 every   month?<br \/>\r\nIs the hair on your shower floor getting thicker while it gets
thinner and thinner on your head?<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nThen Scalp Med Hair Grow
 is for you. Scalp Med Hair Grow is an all natural formulation which includes the
 pure extracts of plants from 3 different continents. This tried and tested formulation
 will reach deep down to cleanse, revitalize and unblock the hair follicles allowing vital   
nutrients to reach the hair roots and allow hair to grow again.<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nScalp
 Med Hair Grow is the only ecological product of its kind capable of treating alopecia 
 efficiently. In the first month, continual use of Scalp Med Hair Grow will recover
 and strengthen the hair follicles. In the second month, your hair will stop 
 falling out altogether. And by the third month, new hair will start to grow.
 <\/font><\/p>\r\n",
 "meta_description":"Scalp Med Hair Grow PC-0004.. Rs. 1199.0000\/- Buy Scalp 
  Med Hair Grow PC-0004.. Lifestyle > Fragrances & Beauty in Pakistan","meta_keyword":
 "Tablet PC, Laptops, Mobile Phones, Watches, China Mobiles, Refurbished Mobiles, 
  Head Phones, Nokia Lumia, Nokia Asha, Samsung Galaxy, Computers, Home Appliances, 
  Printer, Scanners, ipods, ipads, blackberry, htc, iphone, apple, nokia, sony, camera,    
 samsun","product_h1":"",

 }

]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load images you need to use `loadDataWithBaseURL`. To load images from with view data, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267124/how-to-display-image-with-webview-loaddata) link.

Comment: i see this code     webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", dataContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);  but imnot load from asset im load from json url parsing

Comment: I guess you need to take the url.

Answer (score 0):

after getting your JSON String :

```
String content = HttpApi.getContent(URL);
```

you will pass previous URL to load data in webview

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(URL, contentAfterParsing, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

after that you will see the images in webview