# Unable to display Base64 encoded Image

Tags: android

I am trying to display an image encoded in base64 in a WebView.
It's working for most of my users but a few are seeing only weird characters, like shown in the image below.

[image]

This is how I display the image:

```
String b64Image = Base64.encodeToString(fileData, Base64.DEFAULT);
mWebView.loadData(b64Image, "image/jpeg", "base64");
```

The problem occurs on android version 2.3.6 and lower.

Comment: I'm surprised that this works anywhere. Why are you loading it this way, rather than showing the image in an `ImageView`?

Comment: The Image I am trying to load is very big and causes out of memory errors If it's not being loaded into a WebView. Also in a WebView you can smoothly zoom and scroll the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android 2.2 and below you could wrap the image with HTML and load the HTML instead.
For example:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    // Your original code here
   } else {
      byte[] imageRaw = yourImage;
      String image64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageRaw, Base64.DEFAULT);
      String pageData = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + image64 + "\" />";
      //.... etc.
   }
```

- For more details read the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5335274/1600851

There was a bug opened on this which was closed on 2010: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=596