# how to show an image on a web link in image view in android?

Tags: android, url, imageview

i want to show the image on the following link in the webview in my android app. any idea how to do that ? 
image link is given below.
[image link](http://library.namal.edu.pk/cgi-bin/koha/opac-patron-image.pl)

Comment: but your link is broken

Comment: This question has already been asked. [Follow this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267124/how-to-display-image-with-webview-loaddata).

Answer (score 0):

Your link is broken.

- If you want to show remote images in imageview you can use 3rd party library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).
- Without using 3rd party library check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075637/loading-remote-images)
- If you want to load image in webview use web.load(url).

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code use into `Activity On Create`

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebview);   

 String mStringUrl = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><head></head><body><table style=\"width:100%; height:100%;\"><tr><td style=\"vertical-align:middle;\"><img src=\"" + mStringUrl + "\"></td></tr></table></body></html>", "html/css", "utf-8", null);
```

**OR**

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebview);   
String mStringUrl = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(mStringUrl);
```

**In XML**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mwebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"></WebView>
```